# Why it gives me the error: No module named 'urllib.request.urlretrieve'; 'urllib.request' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

In python 3, it gives me this error when importing :
No module named 'urllib.request.urlretrieve'; 'urllib.request' is not a package

```
import urllib
import urllib.request.urlretrieve
def download():
    urllib.urlretrieve ("Simply URL!")
download()
```

Comment: Are you certain you're using Python 3? Did it work without the second import? Do you have another module called urllib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import is wrong.

Correct import looks like:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
def download():
    urlretrieve("url")
download()
```

Or:

```
import urllib.request
def download():
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("url")
download()
```

Take a look at the import Reference: [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html):

Comment: Yeah! the import was wrong.
I made it work by changing it to:

import urllib
import urllib.request